# How to build boost for msvc9.0 instead of msvc10.0?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, bjam

I've run the bootstrap batch and then the bjam exe, but as I have MSVC 2010 it generates the *-vc100-* files in the $boost\stage\lib.

I'm using vc90 libraries so I need the *-vc90-* files, but if I pass the **--toolset=msvc-9.0** option to bjam, it gives me the following errors:

```
...failed compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\wave\build\msvc-9.0\release\link-static\threading-multi\instantiate_cpp_exprgrammar.obj...
compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\wave\build\msvc-9.0\release\link-static\threading-multi\instantiate_cpp_grammar.obj
```

that for each file.

(btw: if no option is specified, it generates the libs for the vc100 without problems)

**Edited:**
Adding the [build.log here](http://www.copypastecode.com/64142/) of the following command:

```
bjam --toolset=msvc-9.0 --with-filesystem >build.log 2>&1
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

solved.

Just needed to add VC9 compiler path to the %PATH% system var.

Answer (score 12):

When compiling with bjam, instead of only `--toolset=msvc` you can specify actual version like `--toolset=msvc-9.0`.